# image segmentation for grains

Tags: image, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am trying to separate the different kinds of grains in an image. And sometimes the image also contains some impurity substance which need to be considered as an extra type.
here are some example images:

corn and beans [image: img]

long rice and wheat [image: img]

I tried to find a general method for the different pics, but the result is not good enough. 
I used flood-fill and some gradient method to get the regions, and try to use clustering method to classify the contains, but the feature selection is a hard problem, I try gabor filter, but it cannot get me a clear boundary, and so does the classification method such as kmeans.

Any ideas about segmentation, getting the contours or classification will be appreciated. thanks!

I try to post some more pics of my current results, but I am sorry that there is the 2 pics restriction for the beginner here.

Comment: grain is usually an oval shape so in standard lighting condition you should be able to detect the specular spot in color intensity. So i would try to find the local maximum of color intensity (peaks). .. Also segmentation based on color homogenity usually helps for this type of images

Comment: @Spektre yeah, finding the major color seems a good way. I will try it. Thank you! I tried using histogram of color, but it didn't work so well.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost a craft work dealing with image processing problems. I would suggest you to use a robust library (such as OpenCV of course) and use cvFindContours function to identify the contours. Also, search for **mathematical morphology**. Basic operators such as erosion and dilation may help you since areas of foreground pixels shrink in size, and holes within those areas become larger and vice-versa. Working with **color segmentation** is also helpful but you might have some troubles since grain color is not uniform. Lastly, **feature extraction** is another way out. **Scale-invariant feature transform** can be used to identify every single grain on the image, based on the fact that it is invariant to linear transformations and illumination issues. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you first! Yes, I do this based on OpenCV, it is really helpful. Do you mean that it is possible to make a template, and then using it to match the whole pic by SIFT. It's really interesting, I'll try it :)